# Como colocar sucessivas matrizes em vector

Tags: java, array, matriz

Tenho as seguintes matrizes de 100 elementos:

```
int [][]matriz1 = {       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0}};


int [][]matriz2 = {       {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
```

Como passo a `matriz1` e `matriz2` para um vector? Na posição 0 do vector fica a `matriz1` e na posição 1 fica a `matriz2`.

Comment: So me pergunto se isso é realmente necessário, sendo que tem recursos melhores e mais simples para lidar com colecoes. Esta pergunta está com cara de ser um [**Problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/28595)

Comment: eu preciso de criar  tabuleiros pre-definidos.Mas para escolher 1 aleatorio tenho de usar uma funçao rand para os que estao inseridos e devolver um tabuleiro

Comment: E só porque precisa criar tabuleiros achou que precisa usar isso ai? Tem jeitos mais fáceis de representar isso, mas para isso, você precisaria explicar melhor o que está fazendo e mostrar o que já fez com um código que seja **[mcve]**. Talvez seja caso de nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Java, [matrizes são na verdade arrays de arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558267). Ou seja, um array no qual cada elemento é outro array.

Então, para colocar essas matrizes em um outro array, basta fazer um "array de matrizes", ou seja, um "array de arrays de arrays":

```
int[][][] v = { matriz1, matriz2 };
```

Sendo assim, `v` é o array que você queria, sendo que `v[0]` contém `matriz1` e `v[1]` contém `matriz2`.