# Como mostrar todos os valores de três matrizes em uma única mensagem sem usar os índices

Tags: java, matriz, for

```
package AlgoritmosII;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Trabalho1 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[][] A = new String[3][3];
        int[][] B = new int[3][3];
        double[][] C = new double[3][3];
        double[] Ordenar_C = new double[9];
        double recebimento, pagamento, maior_saldo=0, aux;
        int flag=0, numero, i, j, n1=0, n2=0, Control, k=0, troca, fim;
        A[0][0]= "Tibúrcio";
        A[0][1]= "Ricardo";
        A[0][2]= "João";
        A[1][0]= "Felisbino";
        A[1][1]= "Seu Zé";
        A[1][2]= "Dona Maria";
        A[2][0]= "Gedonstrôncio";
        A[2][1]= "Batman";
        A[2][2]= "Homem de Ferro";
        B[0][0]= 111;
        B[0][1]= 222;
        B[0][2]= 333;
        B[1][0]= 444;
        B[1][1]= 555;
        B[1][2]= 666;
        B[2][0]= 777;
        B[2][1]= 888;
        B[2][2]= 999;
        C[0][0]= 0.0;
        C[0][1]= 0.0;
        C[0][2]= 0.0;
        C[1][0]= 0.0;
        C[1][1]= 0.0;
        C[1][2]= 0.0;
        C[2][0]= 0.0;
        C[2][1]= 0.0;
        C[2][2]= 0.0;
        while(flag==0) {
            Control = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" 1- Inserir Recebimento \n 2- Inserir Pagamento \n 3- Mostrar informações \n 4- Correntista mais rico \n 5- Saldos em ordem crescente \n 6- Sair"));
            switch (Control) {
                case 1:
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero da conta para Inserir o Recebimento: "));
                    recebimento = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o valor do Recebimento: "));
                    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
                        for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
                            if (numero == B[i][j]) {
                                n1 = i;
                                n2 = j;
                                C[n1][n2] = C[n1][n2] + recebimento;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, A[n1][n2]+" seu saldo atual é de: "+C[n1][n2]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o numero da conta para Retirar o Pagamento: "));
                    pagamento = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o valor do Pagamento: "));
                    for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
                        for (j=0;j<3;j++) {
                            if (numero == B[i][j]) {
                                n1 = i;
                                n2 = j;
                                C[n1][n2] = C[n1][n2] - pagamento;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, A[n1][n2]+" seu saldo atual é de: "+C[n1][n2]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //3–Mostre em apenas uma mensagem todos os Números de Conta, Correntistas e Saldos respectivos.
                    break;
                case 4:
                    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
                        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
                            if (maior_saldo < C[i][j]){
                                maior_saldo = C[i][j];
                                n1 = i;
                                n2 = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"O Correntista mais rico é:\n Correntista: "+A[n1][n2]+"\n Número da conta:  "+B[n1][n2]+"\n Saldo: "+C[n1][n2]);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
                        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
                            Ordenar_C[k] = C[i][j];
                            k++;
                        }
                    }
                    troca = 0;
                    fim = 9-1;
                    while(troca==0){
                        troca=1;
                        for (k=0;k<fim;k++){
                            if (Ordenar_C[k] > Ordenar_C[k+1]){
                                aux = Ordenar_C[k];
                                Ordenar_C[k] = Ordenar_C[k+1];
                                Ordenar_C[k+1] = aux;
                                troca=0;
                            }
                        }
                        fim = fim-1;
                    }
                    for (k=0;k<9;k++){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Os saldos ordenados em forma crescente ("+k+"): \n"+Ordenar_C[k]);
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Algo de errado não esta certo ;3");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meu problema é o case 3: "Mostre em apenas uma mensagem todos os Números de Conta, Correntistas e Saldos respectivos". Meu professor me disse:

> -"Use concatenação de texto em uma variável. Depois só um showmessage".
>
> -"Dica: for para concatenar texto depois um showmessage".

Eu realmente ainda não compreendi como eu poderia fazer isso mas se possível eu gostaria de colocar:

Nome: +A

Numero da conta: +B

Saldo: +C

Mas tendo de utilizar apenas uma mensagem para isso me confundiu um pouco, e eu gostaria de saber o que eu poderia fazer para mostrar essas informações, sem usar os índices (ex: Nome: + `A[0][0]`, Numero Conta: + `B[0][0]`, Saldo: + `C[0][0]`).

Comment: Porque tem que ser feito sem usar os índices?

Comment: Pois se eu utilizasse matrizes maiores ainda poderia utilizar esse código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu diria que o professor já deu todas as dicas necessárias:

> "Use concatenação de texto em uma variável. Depois só um `showmessage`".
>
> "Dica: `for` para concatenar texto depois um `showmessage`".

Então primeiro você cria uma variável que vai ter a mensagem. Depois, use dois laços `for` para percorrer as "matrizes" ([na verdade são arrays de arrays](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355793/112052), mas enfim), e vá concatenando os respectivos valores nessa variável. Como são várias concatenações de `String`, eu sugiro usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(A[i][j]).append(" ").append(B[i][j]).append(" ").append(C[i][j]).append("\n");
    }
}
String mensagem = sb.toString();
```

E pronto, no final a variável `mensagem` terá todos os dados concatenados. Eu coloquei um espaço separando o nome, número da conta e saldo, e coloquei uma quebra de linha no final (o `\n`). A mensagem ficou assim:

```
Tibúrcio 111 0.0
Ricardo 222 0.0
João 333 0.0
Felisbino 444 0.0
Seu Zé 555 0.0
Dona Maria 666 0.0
Gedonstrôncio 777 0.0
Batman 888 0.0
Homem de Ferro 999 0.0
```

Você pode mudar a mensagem do jeito que quiser (como colocar uma vírgula separando os dados, ou qualquer outro formato que desejar). E uma vez tendo a mensagem, basta mostrá-la com `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` (ou o que quer que você esteja usando para exibir as mensagens).

Vale dizer que não tem como fugir de usar os índices, pois você quer concatenar `A[i][j]` com `B[i][j]` com `C[i][j]`. Sem saber os valores de `i` e `j`, não tem como saber quais dados serão concatenados na ordem correta.

---

Claro que você também poderia fazer sem um `StringBuilder`, criando a `String` e concatenando diretamente nela:

```
String mensagem = "";
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < A[i].length; j++) {
        mensagem += A[i][j] + " " + B[i][j] + " " + C[i][j] + "\n";
    }
}
```

Mas ao fazer concatenações em um *loop*, é mais eficiente usar um `StringBuilder`, conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052).

---

Esse código assume que `A`, `B` e `C` possuem a mesma quantidade de elementos (tanto que eu uso `A.length` - o tamanho do array `A` - sem verificar se `B` e `C` têm esse mesmo tamanho). Se a quantidade for diferente, teria que verificar antes se os tamanhos são iguais e tratá-los de acordo (não parece ser o caso do exercício), para que não ocorra o erro de [*index out of bound*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/112052).

Por fim, sugiro usar as [convenções de código do Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/codeconvtoc-136057.html) e usar nomes de variáveis que começam com letras minúsculas. E procure dar nomes mais significativos também (por exemplo: em vez de `A`, `B` e `C`, poderia ser `nomes`, `contas` e `saldos`). Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas [nomes melhores ajudam na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).